# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-mediasession:2.8.4

Tags: android, github, build.gradle

I just pull NEWPIPE from git and load in MY Android Studio
and stuck over this two dependency.
I added dependencies of gradle file.
I hope it will help to find a bug.
also added

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()}
```

in project level build.gradle file

```
    dependencies {    
        implementation 'com.github.TeamNewPipe:NewPipeExtractor:32d316330c26'    
        implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
        implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
        implementation "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
        implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
        implementation "com.android.support:preference-v14:${supportLibVersion}"
        implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

        implementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2' //4.11

        implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
        implementation 'com.github.nirhart:ParallaxScroll:dd53d1f9d1'
        implementation 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:4.2.1'

//Failed to resolve: com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-mediasession:2.8.4
//Failed to resolve: com.google.android.exoplayer:2.8.4


 implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:${exoPlayerLibVersion}"
        implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-mediasession:${exoPlayerLibVersion}"

        debugImplementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho:${stethoLibVersion}"
        debugImplementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho-urlconnection:${stethoLibVersion}"
        debugImplementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

        implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2'
        implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
        implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.1.1'

        implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:${roomDbLibVersion}"
        implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:${roomDbLibVersion}"
        annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:${roomDbLibVersion}"

        implementation "frankiesardo:icepick:${icepickLibVersion}"
        annotationProcessor "frankiesardo:icepick-processor:${icepickLibVersion}"

        debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:${leakCanaryLibVersion}"
        releaseImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:${leakCanaryLibVersion}"

        implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${okHttpLibVersion}"
        debugImplementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:${stethoLibVersion}"
    }
```

can any one help me to sort out this issue

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was facing the same issue. Solved by adding `url 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/'` to buld.gradle at a project level within `allprojects` section.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/'
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Its perfect 
Thanks for your quick response.